# BackupPC error "No files dumped for share"

Tags: server, windows, samba

I had BackupPC working fine for years but I wanted to move it to another server. The backuppc copies all the files but backup = 0 Type = partial Filled = yes (which is OK)

Backup#  Type Filled
0-----------partial yes

I can't resolve the following issue:

```
tarExtract: Done: 0 errors, 15 filesExist, 2342001 sizeExist, 1120139 sizeExistComp, 155 filesTotal, 8019734 sizeTotal
Got fatal error during xfer (No files dumped for share foo)
Backup aborted (No files dumped for share foo)
Not saving this as a partial backup since it has fewer files than the prior one (got 155 and 0 files versus 500)
```

Contents of file /var/lib/backuppc/pc/*******/XferLOG.bad.z, modified 2018-01-28 18:50:42

```
Running: /usr/bin/smbclient \\\\*******\\Scan -I 192.168.0.106 -U backuppc -E -d 1 -c tarmode\ full -Tc -
full backup started for share Scan
Xfer PIDs are now 1972,1971
Domain=[********] OS=[Windows 10 Home 16299] Server=[Windows 10 Home 6.3]
tar:316  tarmode is now full, system, hidden, noreset, quiet
tar:712  Total bytes received: 29524103
```

For those who asked for more info:

Backup failed on: `(No files dumped for share ...)`

this is the fatal error I got every single time when backuppc runs

Note: rsync works OK on Linux clients, only smb fails on Windows clients.

- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (Xenial)
- BackupPC - Version 3.3.1
- Samba - Version 4.3.11-Ubuntu

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

P.S. I was not able to got work with samba. Change to rsyncd and works fine since.

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://askubuntu.com/posts/995319/edit) with the following information: which software do you use, on which Ubuntu version, which errors do you get, which exact question do you have.

Comment: I am definitely doing something consistently wrong as I get above mentioned error from three windows clients: (Windows 10, Windows 7, Windows XP).

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, how did you set up the current backup system, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in Bionic 18.04, however the parameter "$Conf{BackupZeroFilesIsFatal} = 0" parameter for SMB Xfer, needs to be changed for upgrading hosts.  Relevant link at Debian bug #820693:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=820963#82

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in Bionic 18.04, however the parameter `$Conf{BackupZeroFilesIsFatal} = 0` for SMB Xfer needs to be changed for upgrading hosts.

The relevant link is [Debian bug #820693](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=820963#82).